# Can I use same curl handle for different urls? (trying to download data from multiple pages of one url)

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, libcurl

I am trying to download data from one url which has multiple pages. 
ex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=15
I would like to download all the data from different pages
ex) pages=1, pages=2, pages=3 etc..

If I create a curl handle with one url with certain page,
will it be okay to replace urls (only page number) without worrying about performance?

I've created curl handle every time I move to next page and download the data. 
I got an advice from other people that it would be better to create a ssl session and persist its connection, so that I don't have to go through all the SSL handshake whenever I create SSL connections.

Accordint to Libcurl page, it is recommending to use same handle for performance, but I am not sure I could do it with different URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should re-use the same `curl` instance whenever possible. Just keep on repeating `curl_easy_setopt(CURLOPT_URL, ...); curl_easy_perform(...);` calls.

Additional notes:

1. You can download multiple URLs in parallel if you use the [`curl_multi_init`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-app.html) interface ([example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_init.html)).
2. StackExchange has a [very good REST API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs). There is no need to scrape it.